# Large Sound Overlay

Tags: audio

This just started happening today...I noticed that when I'm in Chrome, Brave, etc and as I increase the sound from my keyboard, I get this large sound overlay (back, pause, forward) option.

I've looked online for an answer, and looks like it has happened to Spotify users, but I don't use Spotify. So it must be something related more to Windows than Spotify in this case.

Thanks for any of your help in getting this removed!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUcGD.jpg)

Comment: I should mention I installed the HighVolumeOSD as a temp solution. I like seeing the sound part, but more interested in getting rid of that massive banner.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - It was a setting within Chrome:

chrome://flags/#enable-media-session-service

Disable that setting.